# app(debug) build by android studio has no permission for 'files' folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I use Android Studio(2.1.1) with gradle(2.10) with SDK23(Android M) to build project. After build apk and install it to android phone, I found that the '/data/data/com.xxx/files' folder of app(debug) is drwx------. However, if I build a release apk(signed) and install it to phone, the 'files' folder is drwxr--r--. And if I  use eclipse(SDK20, Android4.4) to build it, both debug and release are drwxr--r--. This is quite boring, how can I change 'files' folder to drwxr--r-- when build debug apk?
[image]

Comment: In SDK 23 you have to get runtime permissions have you got that?

Comment: @SohailZahid, I'm not sure, I totally **not change any code** in release apk, but release app is ok

Comment: Might be you are targeting api < 23 in eclipse and API 23 in Android studio.